# Conditional replacing - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace

I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, "."], 'col2': [3, 4,5]}
x = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
x[x["col1"] == "."]
```

I want to replace the `"."` with `np.NaN` using the third line, but I can't figure out the right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `df.replace()`:

```
import numpy as np

x.replace('.',np.nan)
```

Returns:

```
   col1  col2
0   1.0     3
1   2.0     4
2   NaN     5
```

Note that this will replace all occurrences of `'.'` with `NaN` in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the '.' in 'col1' only, then you can do:

```
x.loc[x.col1 == '.', 'col1'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

call replace on a series rather than entire df

```
x.col1=x.col1.replace('.',np.nan)
```

can also use np.where

```
np.where((x['col1'] == '.'), np.nan,x['col1'])
```